# WebBrowser component navigation through multiple pages does not work

Tags: delphi, browser

Trying to navigate using WebBrowser component automatically through code it doesn't work. The navigation includes the login page and after that some other pages. The first page button login works fine. On second page the next button needed an application.processmessages before executing to make it work. On the next/third page I cannot make automatically the next button to work.

CODE:

```
//CLICK BUTTON
function clickForm1(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; FieldName: string): Boolean;
var
  i, j: Integer;
  FormItem: Variant;
begin
  Result := False;
  //no form on document
  if WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.all.tags('FORM').Length = 0 then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;
  //count forms on document
  for I := 0 to WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.forms.Length - 1 do
  begin
    FormItem := WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.forms.Item(I);
    for j := 0 to FormItem.Length - 1 do
    begin
  try
    //when the fieldname is found, try to fill out
    if FormItem.Item(j).Name = FieldName then
    begin
      FormItem.Item(j).click;
      Result := True;
    end;
  except
    Exit;
  end;
end;
  end;
end;

//SEARCH INSIDE THE MEMO
procedure TForm2.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  a: string;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  Memo1.Lines.Text := ' ' + Memo1.Lines.Text;
  for i := 0 to Length(Memo1.Lines.Text) - Length(edit7.Text) do
  begin
    a := Copy(Memo1.Lines.Text, i, Length(edit7.Text));
    if CheckBox1.Checked = True then   //FIND CASE Sensitive
    begin
      if a = edit7.Text then
      begin
        find := True;
        x    := 2;
        Memo1.Lines.Text := Copy(Memo1.Lines.Text, 2,             Length(Memo1.Lines.Text) - 1);
    Memo1.SetFocus;
    Memo1.SelStart  := i - 2;
    Memo1.SelLength := Length(edit7.Text);
    break;
  end;
end
    else                              
    begin
      if lowercase(a) = lowercase(edit7.Text) then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Text := Copy(Memo1.Lines.Text, 2,     Length(Memo1.Lines.Text) - 1);
        find := True;
        x    := 2;
        Memo1.SetFocus;
        Memo1.SelStart  := i - 2;
        Memo1.SelLength := Length(edit7.Text);
        break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


//HTML TO MEMO
procedure TForm2.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    iall : IHTMLElement;
begin
   if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
   begin
     iall := (WebBrowser1.Document AS IHTMLDocument2).body;

     while iall.parentElement <> nil do
     begin
       iall := iall.parentElement;
     end;
     memo1.Text := iall.outerHTML;
   end;
end;


procedure TForm2.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
var
Document: IHtmlDocument2;
CurWebrowser : IWebBrowser;
TopWebBrowser: IWebBrowser;
WindowName   : string;

ovElements: OleVariant;
i: Integer;
begin

CurWebrowser := pDisp as IWebBrowser;
TopWebBrowser := (ASender as TWebBrowser).DefaultInterface;
if CurWebrowser=TopWebBrowser then
 begin

 button6.Click;               // HTML TO MEMO

 TRY
 button7.Click;                      //SEARCH LOGIN FORM
 if find=true then Begin
    clickForm1(WebBrowser1, 'move');  //CLICK LOGIN BUTTON
 End Else begin Null; End;
 FINALLY  find:=false; END;

 TRY
 button8.Click;            //SEARCH HOME (AFTER LOGIN) FORM
 if find1=true then Begin
 Application.ProcessMessages;//NEEDED IN ORDER THE BUTTON TO BE PRESSED.
 clickForm1(WebBrowser1, 'refresh');  //CLICK NEXT PAGE BUTTON
 End;
 FINALLY find1:=false;END;

 TRY
 button9.Click;             //SEARCH WORKLIST FORM
 if find2=true then Begin
 clickForm1(WebBrowser1, 'next');  //CLICK NEW FORM BUTTON
 End;
 FINALLY find2:=false;END;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: if the page is being posted back to the server (like for example "move") you need to process the next page/step on DocumentComplete again, because the webbrowser will load a new document. so each step should be handled separately on each DocumentComplete event. if the action is done on the client side with javascript, you need to give the DOM some time to process the action to become idle, or hook directly into the script events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I use the onDocumentComplete Method again&again? On the above example I inserted a Try/Except method in order to search every time the title of the web page that is loaded and to press accrordingly the right button.

Comment: you could for example check the URL or inspect the DOM each time the onDocumentComplet is fired to determine which step/page to process next.

Comment: That is what I am doing but I am faceing the problem with submit buttons of each web page that is loading. On the first web page the submit button is pressed. On the 2nd web page that is loading in order the submit button to be pressed I have to execute before an Application.Processmessages. On the third web page the submit button doesn/t work automatically. BUT Trying to press it by code on an external button just for test, the code executed ok!...

Comment: @kobik is right.  Ime, the cleanest way to do multi-step navigation is to write what to do to get from one page to the next as a separate routine, each with the signature of OnDocumentComplete, then assign the WB's OnDocumentComplete to each of them in turn, as navigation proceeds.

Comment: But How can I implement this since I have only one Webbrowser1. On which event of the whole code can I map each webpage + corresponding Ondocumentcomplete event?

Comment: You can have as many procedures as you like, e.g. A, B, C, [...] on your form with the OnDocumentComplete signature, then assign them to your WB in turn, e.g. WebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete := A, [...] := B, etc.  Try it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I cannot interprete it to code. 1. Should I use multiple procedures TForm2.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete with the same name? 2. Where to insert WebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete := A...? On the CreateForm? The case is 3 webpages and in order to go from the first page to second one I have to press a button. The same from the second to the third one. Hence On the Webbrowser.OndocumentComplete event of the form I check the url that is loaded each time and automatically I press the next page button...But it doesnt work well

Comment: I will try to post you an example of what I'm trying to explain, as an answer (because it will not fit in a comment) tomorrow morning if someone hasn't posted you another answer in the meantime.

Comment: The problem seems to be not on my code But when I go from the second to the third web page, A change on the fields is happened (filtering) on the webpage but not to the whole webbrowser in order the ondocumentcomplete event to take place. Does anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much you know about working with Event Handlers in code.

Objects like Forms and WebBrowsers typically have one or more event properties that are used to define what happens when the event occurs. So, an event property is a property of an object that can hold the information necessary to invoke (call) a procedure (or function, but not usually) of the same object or another one.  The procedure to call has to have the right "signature" for the type definition of the event.  If it does then an "event handler" can be assigned to the event *property* in code, as I'll show below.

One can use event properties and event-handling code in Delphi in a simple way, without knowing any of this, just by going to the Events tab of the Object Inspector and double-clicking next to one of the event names.  What that actually does is to create a new handler procedure and to assign it to the corresponding event property of the object (well, not quite, actually that assignment is done at run-time when the host form is loaded).

What I mean by "signature" is the routine type (procedure or function) and its list of parameters, and their types, in its definition.

So, for a WebBrowser, the signature of the OnDocumentComplete event is

```
procedure (Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OLEVariant);
```

The clever thing is that you can assign the OnDocumentComplete *property* to
any procedure of an object that has the exact same signature.  The event type for the WB's OnDocumentComplete is defined in the import unit ShDocVw, btw

So, let's suppose you write three methods that contain the code you want to run
when the WB completes loading URLs A, B and C, respectively:

```
procedure TForm1.DocCompleteA(Sender: TObject; const
    pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OLEVariant);
begin
  //  Do your stuff for arrival at site/page A here
  // Then update NavigationOK flag to reflect if you succeeded or failed

  if NavigationOK then begin
    WebBrowser1.OnDocumentComplete := DocCompleteB;
    //  Now navigate to site/page B
  end
  else
    WebBrowser1.OnDocumentComplete := Nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.DocCompleteB(Sender: TObject; const
    pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OLEVariant);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.DocCompleteC(Sender: TObject; const
    pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OLEVariant);
begin

end;
```

Then, you can assign the WB's OnDocumentComplete property to each of them in turn,
with something like the code at the end of DocCompleteA which updates the WB's OnDocumentComplete to the code needed for B, and so on, in turn.  The NavigationOK variable is just a flag to indicate that our navigation stays "on course" as it progresses.  If it gets set to false because something went wrong, we set the WB's OnDocumentComplete to Nil, so that it does nothing next time the event occurs.

Then, you can kick off the whole "tour" of sites with something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.NavigateSites;
begin
  NavigationOK := True;
  WebBrowser1.OnDocumentComplete := DocCompleteA;
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(...); // Navigate to site A

end;
```

Of course, you don't *have* to do the updating of the WB's OnDocumentComplete property and navigation to the next URL in the current DocCompleteX.  In fact, it's probably clearer if you do those if a higher level procedure like the NavigateSites one, and more easily maintainable, which can be important if you're navigating others' sites, which are apt to be changed without any prior warning.

Comment: Thank you so much for yout time. I am gonna try it right away

Comment: @MarcielFonseca:  IIrc, I wrote this answer with code for D7, which uses a rather ancient version of the MSHTML.Pas import unit.  If you are getting that error,  maybe it's because you are using a different (later) version of MSHTML.Pas.  But I don't follow why you would get this error with DocCompleteB but not, since you don't mention it, DocCompleteA.  In any case, all you need do is to use the IDE to create an OnDocumentComplete event for your version of TWebBrowser and just copy the parameter list from that.